# QSignalMapper with signal argument and extra argument

Tags: qt, arguments, signals

I knew that QSignalMapper work well for the condition like this:

```
QSignalMapper *signalMapper = new QSignalMapper(this);
connect(signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(int)), this, SIGNAL(SetSlice(int)));

connect(this->ui->button_1, SIGNAL(slicked()), signalMapper, SLOT(map()));
connect(this->ui->button_2, SIGNAL(clicked()), signalMapper, SLOT(map()));
connect(this->ui->button_3, SIGNAL(clicked()), signalMapper, SLOT(map()));
```

Now I want to implement 3 sliders all have one SLOT like buttons:

```
QSignalMapper *signalMapper = new QSignalMapper(this);
connect(signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(int)), this, SIGNAL(SetSlice(int)));

connect(this->ui->verticalSlider_1, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), signalMapper, SLOT(map()));
connect(this->ui->verticalSlider_2, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), signalMapper, SLOT(map()));
connect(this->ui->verticalSlider_3, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), signalMapper, SLOT(map()));
```

As you can see, this is contradictory with the consistent rule between SIGNAL and SLOT.
Is there a workaround here? I am using Qt4.

Comment: Do you need to know which slider invoked slot?

Comment: Yes, that's the reason I use QSignalMapper at the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QSignalMapper` is not about sending arguments from signals to slots but to let signal receiver know "who" was that or what data use. If you need to know both value and sender you either can use some internal class mapping, or use `QObject *` mapper and then cast `QObject *` to slider.

```
QSignalMapper * mapper = new QSignalMapper(this);
connect(mapper, SIGNAL(map(QWidget *)), this, SLOT(SetSlice(QWidget *)));

mapper->setMapping(this->ui->verticalSlider_1, this->ui->verticalSlider_1);
mapper->setMapping(this->ui->verticalSlider_2, this->ui->verticalSlider_2);
mapper->setMapping(this->ui->verticalSlider_3, this->ui->verticalSlider_3);
```

And here's slot body:

```
void YourClass::SetSlice(QWidget *wgt)
{
    QSlider * slider = qobject_cast<QSlider *>(wgt);

    if(slider) {
        SetSlice(slider->value());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, thanks, I never thought parse QWidget itself. What's the efficiency compared to 3 sliders with 3 SLOTs?